# Left shifting operation on int

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

On IndiaBix.com I came across the following question.As per my experience level(beginner in C) the output of above should be 0  `(10000000 << 1 is 00000000)` but it came out to be 256,after going some deeper I found that we are printing using **%d** which supports 4 bytes so the output is 256 instead of 0.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
    int main()
    {
        unsigned char i = 128;
        printf("%d \n", i << 1);
        return 0;
    }
```

Now Consider the following Example

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int i = 2147483648;(bit 31 = 1 and b0 to b30 are 0)
    printf("%d \n", i<<1);
    return 0;
}
```

When I left shift the above I get 0 as the output, As %d supports value of int the output should be 0 but when I Changed %d to %ld the output is still 0. As %ld supports values upto long int the output should not be 0.Why i am getting 0 as the output.

Comment: Changing thhe `printf` format specifier doesn't change the size of the type you are actually doing your calculation on. `unsigned int` is (not guaranteed, but usually) 4 bytes. Using the wrong `printf` specifier for your type is illegal: [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) can give you very confusing results, including crashing, printing something odd, or even appearing to work normally.

Comment: You might want to read about [*integral promotion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast#Integral_promotion) which causes your `unsigned char` variable to be promoted to an `int` before the shift operation.

Comment: mind the format specifiers, http://trust-in-soft.com/printing-an-unsigned-char-with-x-or-u-is-not-absolutely-correct/

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, `i` is promoted to `int`, which can store at least 32767, then shift is calculated. As a result, the result became 256.

In the second case, if your `unsigned int`  is 32-bit long, it is calculated in `unsigned int` and the result wraps. As a result, the result became 0.

You have to cast to larger type to get what you want.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int i = 2147483648;//(bit 31 = 1 and b0 to b30 are 0)
    printf("%"PRIu64" \n", (uint64_t)i<<1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not the `%d` or `%ld` that matters here.

Its probably because the *size of unsigned int* on your machine in 4 bytes.

Also you can't use `%ld` with *unsigned int*. It is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that 2147483648 (80000000h) will fit inside your 32 bit unsigned int, but it will not fit inside the signed `int` that printf expects when you use the `%d` specifier. Instead, use the `%u` specifier.

When that is fixed, note that `0x80000000 << 1` is *supposed* to be 0 if unsigned int is 32 bits.

Changing the format specifier of `printf` to `%ld` does not change the type of the expression! You need to change *both* the format specifier *and* the expression, if you want a larger type.

You are getting tricked by the behavior of the first `char` print. The reason why `%d` works there is because printf (like any variadic function) internally promotes all arguments to be at least the size of `int`. So the expression got implicitly promoted to `int` and as it happens, that matches with `%d`.

Though in the case of `my_char << n`, the `<<` operator already integer promote both operands to `int` and the result of a shift always has the type of the possibly promoted left operand.

As you can tell, the various implicit type promotion rules in C aren't trivial and can therefore easily create bugs. It is one of many well-known flaws of the language.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 3 **The integer promotions** are performed on each of the operands.
>   The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand....

and (6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers)

> 2. ...If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted > by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to
>      an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int. **These are
>      called the integer promotions**.58) All other types are unchanged by
>      the integer promotions.

This means that an operand of type `unsigned char` is promoted to type `int` because type `int` can represent all values of type `unsigned char`.

So in expression

```
i << 1
```

operand `i` is promoted to type `int` and you will get (let's assume that type int has `32` bits)

```
0x00000080 << 1
```

After the operation you will get result

```
0x00000100
```

that corresponds to decimal

```
256
```

and this statement

```
printf("%d \n", i << 1);
```

outputs this result.

Now consider this code snippet

```
unsigned int i = 2147483648;(bit 31 = 1 and b0 to b30 are 0)
printf("%d \n", i<<1);
```

Here `i` can be represented like

```
0x80000000
```

The integer promotions are applied to types that have the conversion rank less than the rank of type int.

So the integer promotions will not be applied to variable `i` because it does not has a rank less than the rank of `int`.

After the operations you will get

```
0x00000000
```

that is you will get decimal

```
0
```

and this statement

```
printf("%d \n", i<<1);
```

will correctly output this zero because its representation is the same for unsigned and signed integer objects.

Even if you write for example

```
printf( "%lld \n", ( long long int )( i<<1 ));
```

you will get the same result because the type of expression `i << 1` in any case is `unsigned int`

However if you will write

```
printf( "%lld \n", ( long long int )i << 1 );
```

then operand `i` will be converted to type `long long int` and you will get

```
0x0100000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing %d to %id will not be effective 
Change datatype to unsigned it to that will help you to increase your integer limit